# Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group

Tags: java, regex

I need to capture a repeated pattern inside a line.

For instance :
`toto#titi#` or `toto#titi#tutu` or `toto#titi#tutu#tata#` etc...

and this is my regex : `(?:[\w]*#){1,}`

And I need to capture toto, titi, tutu...

But even if `Matcher.matches()` returns true, the only group I have is the last captured pattern :

`toto#titi#`-> 1 group `titi`, `toto#titi#tutu` -> 1 group `tutu`, `toto#titi#tutu#tata` -> 1 group `tata`.

Could you tell me why and how to solve it?

Many thanks

Adrien

Comment: Why not use `String#split` on `#`?

Comment: `String.split()` works in this particular case and is faster. If you want to stick to RegEx (for more dynamic patterns for example), you can refer to my answer.

Comment: @anubhava -I think, he can't use split because he wants only Strings with repeated pattern. example `abc#titi#tutu` --> *maybe* he wants only `titi` and `tutu` here.

Comment: I can't use String#split because this is just a little part of a biggest regex ;)

Comment: ok if you provide more context I can look into this.

Comment: it's ok @anubhava, AlexR gave me an answer ;) Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want this RegEx: `(\w+)#?` and go through all matches by

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)#?");
Pattern check = Pattern.compile("^[\\w#]+$");
if (!check.matcher(input).matches()) // As requested: Sanity check
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bogus input received :(");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    String matched = m.group(1); // Iterates over the occurences
    System.out.println("I found " + matched);
}
```

Output for `tata#titi#tutu`:

```
I found tata
I found titi
I found tutu
```

Not that in such a simple case the code,

```
for (String matched : input.split("#"))
    System.out.println("I found " + matched);
```

is essentially equivalent. So you aren't bound to use RegEx here.
By essentially equivalent, I mean that `String.split("#")` will give you empty `String`s from input like `#tata#titi##tutu` (2 total here), while the regex would require to be altered to `(\w*)#?` to find those as well.

Comment: groups() are Ok, but I need to have Matcher.matches() to true !

Comment: @Modzful why? Matcher.find() works. If you really need it, you'll need a separate RegEx to check for that: `String.matches("^[\w#]+$")` works here.

Comment: Is it not possible to build a single regEx for matches() et groups()? :/

Comment: @Modzful A dynamic number of groups isn't well supported with Java Regex. The provided example is as clean as you can get.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I thought at first that it was about this kind of pitfalls. http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "toto#titi#tutu#tata#";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2})(\\1)(?=#)"); // you need too capture the group.
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }

    }
```

O/P :

```
toto
titi
tutu
tata
```

Note: Returns the same output if string is  `"jfgjd#toto#titi#tutu#tata#sdas";`

Comment: Hmmm. I need to capture jfgjd,toto,titi,tutu,tata,sdas with `jfgjd#toto#titi#tutu#tata#sdas`

Comment: @Modzful - then a simple `split()` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "jfgjd#toto#titi#tutu#tata#sdas";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(?=#)"); // you need too capture the group.
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }

    }
```

After small modification you get

```
jfgjd
toto
titi
tutu
tata
```